# Ajax form within a form with no layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

So I'm new to rails and having a little bit of trouble my situation is that I have a products model that has some Images attached to it. I would like on my products page to have a button to create a new image via ajax.

Inside my products _form view i have:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@product) do |f| %>
<%= f.error_notification %>
<div class="inputs">
<%= f.input :name %>
<%= f.input :description, :input_html => {:class => "wysihtml5 span6", :style => "height:400px;"} %>
<%= f.association :images, label_method: :name, value_method: :id %>
<h4>Upload new file</h4>
</div>
<%= link_to 'Add Image', '/images/new', :remote => true, :"data-replace" => "#image-form" %>
<div id="image-form">
</div>
<div class="actions">
  <%= f.button :submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

And it does successfully Load the page via ajax.
But I would like to load it without the layout. Is this possible?
Do I need to create a new action that renders the partial form and has no layout??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I'm assuming you have it requesting and returning html and not js?  There are a couple of thoughts I have on this:

If you only ever need for this request to return from an AJAX request, then you could simply tell the controller to always `render layout: false`

If you would like to allow the controller to return a full page on occasion, you can either accept an argument in the get request and change the output accordingly, or you can tell the controller to:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # will render default with no block passed
  format.js { render layout: false }
end
```

This should just work with the code in your form right now, because the `:remote => true` tells the controller to return js if possible, but accessing images/new from your browser will request html.
(Requesting js does not mean that you actually have to return js, as I don't in this case; it's up to you to take the proper action with what is returned.  Some might consider it bad form, though, to return something other than what is technically requested.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following in your action. Let your action is new.

```
def new
 #your code goes here
 render :layout => false
end
```